# Graph with super nodes where each super node may have one or more sub-nodes in it

Tags: graph-theory, network

I have a question related to a problem I'm working on currently which is related to graph theory and complete sub-graph of size k (clique of size k).
Let us say we have a graph where each node has one or more sub-nodes inside it.
And we define a connection between two super nodes if there are at least one connection (edge) between the sub-nodes in each of the super nodes.
For example, let us have two super nodes A and B, where A has two sub-nodes (a1, a2) and the super node B has two sub-nodes (b1, b2) if there are any edge between sub-nodes of A and the sub-nodes of B we can say that the super nodes A and B are connected.

I need to know the terminologies of this kind of graph and if there is anything related to it in the field of graph theory.

Comment: It sounds like you are making 'hierarchical' graphs. That is, your 'super  nodes' are at the top of the hierarchy, and the 'sub-nodes' are at the bottom. From a quick search, it seems like this concept is mostly used in graph layout, however.